# How do I change all the values in a column whose value is contained in more than one row?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Let's say I have a simple table with two columns `userid` and `email`.

How can I change all the `email` values where the `email` value exists in more than one row?

For example, say the `email` value `blah@blah.com` exists in 4 rows.  I don't want to delete those 4 rows, I just want to set the `email` column of all 4 of those rows to `''`.

What query would do that in MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Update t
Set t.Email = ''
Where t.Email in (Select email from YourTable group by email having count(*)>1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This request get the emails that exist in more than 1 row:

```
SELECT email, COUNT(email) AS c
FROM table 
GROUP BY email
HAVING c > 1
```

So you just have to use it in your update query:

```
UPDATE table SET email = ''
WHERE email IN (
     SELECT email, COUNT(email) AS c
     FROM table 
     GROUP BY email
     HAVING c > 1
)
```

Comment: Not sure but MySQL might tell you that _you can't specify target table '<table name>' for update in FROM clause_.